# C++ How can i constantly check if a variable changes in a class?

Tags: c++

So, I've started programming classes last year. I would like to know how i can make a function in a class that lets me check if a variable has reached a certain threshold and then modify it.
I tried this but i think it just stops at the cycle and never resumes.
It is public and i call it through the main.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
class Numbers{
private: 
    int Limit, Current, counter;

public:
 
        void addCurrent(int a) { Current += a; }
        int getCurrent() {return Current; }
        int getLimit() {return Limit; }
        int getCounter() {return counter; }
         

    void Check() {
        while (true) {
            if (Current >= Limit) {
                counter++;
                Current -= Limit; 
                Limit = Limit * counter;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I call it in the main like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    Numbers.one;
    one.Check();
    one.addCurrent(200);
    cout<< one.getLimit() << "/" << one.getCurrent() << "/" << one.getCounter();
}
```

Since I'm at a really beginner level I would like to keep it simple, but any help is appriciated.
Thanks

Comment: What do you expect the output of that program to be?

Comment: So, in your loop if current is greater than or equal to limit, you decrease current and increase limit. Your loop either never runs, or never ends.

Comment: @MilesBudnek just the new Limit and the counter i miss wrote that actually

Comment: @Elia Zelotti What is that Numbers.one;?

Comment: @EliaZelotti No, your expectation is unclear since `Limit`, `Current`, and `counter` are all uninitialized.  Depending on how I initialize them I can make your program print out any three numbers I want.  What three numbers do _you_ want?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The declaration of the object of the class i'd say

Comment: @MilesBudnek just counter and Limit.

Comment: @EliaZelotti looks like a syntax error.  Did you mean `Numbers one;`?

Comment: Don't loop in `Check`.  Put a call to `Check` at the end of `addCurrent`.

Comment: @EliaZelotti No, what _values_ do you want printed out?  For instance `720/46/6` is one possible output, but it may not be the _right_ output that you want.

Comment: You're only using one thread, so your program can only do one thing at a time.  While it's busy running `Check` it won't return and run the other stuff.  All the code after your call to `Check` will not run.

Comment: Ideally the way to see the problem with this code would be to step-through it with a debugger.  Is that something you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put your logic into `addCurrent`:

```
class Numbers{
private: 
    int Limit = 1;
    int Current = 0;
    int counter = 0;

public:

    void addCurrent(int a) {
        Current += a;
        Check();
    }
    int getCurrent() {return Current; }
    int getLimit() {return Limit; }
    int getCounter() {return counter; }

    void Check() {
        while (Current >= Limit) {
            counter++;
            Current -= Limit; 
            Limit = Limit * counter;
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    Numbers one;
    one.addCurrent(200);
    cout<< one.getLimit() << "/" << one.getCurrent() << "/" << one.getCounter();
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7598ee58e63940d)

Note that I had to make some assumptions about what behavior you want and what values `Limit`, `Current`, and `counter` should have initially.  It's also not clear if you want the `Check` logic to continue until `Current < Limit` or if you want it applied once.